How do I solve non-linear optimization problems using Gurobi in the pyomo framework?
I am trying to solve a non linear (specifically exponential) constrained problem using Gurobi in the pyomo framework. The solver gives an error saying "model constraint cannot be written in LP form". The same problem is solved in the gurobipy framework.
I have used the inbuilt function in pyomo core (pc) in order to define the constraint. (refer to the following block of code)
model.con3=pe.Constraint(rule= model.expx == pc.exp(model.x) - 25)
The solver is giving me an error that: "ValueError: Model constraint contains nonlinear terms that cannot be written to LP format"
I have selected follwing options for the solver:
solver = "gurobi"
solver_config = {"msg": 1,
"keepFiles": 0,
"options": {"FuncNonlinear":1, "NonConvex":2}}
I have implemented the same code using gurobipy and setting the parameter m.params.FuncNonlinear = 1; the code works fine and the problem is solved. Is there a way to solve non linear optimization in Gurobi in the pyomo framework ?
Thank you!

Not sure it's possible.  Maybe try the "GurobiPersistent" solver in Pyomo, and see if there's any change.  Perhaps this avoids the intermediate file writing stage.

For using Gurobi for non-linear optimization in Pyomo use
opt = SolverFactory('gurobi')
opt.options['NonConvex'] = 2
